# Initialization of a struct containing an array in VST

Tags: verifiable-c

My question isn't one of correctness, so much as efficiency. I am currently attempting to verify a function in C which relies on a `typedef struct` containing an array and an `int`. However, I have noticed that the array is being initialized in `clightgen` with the normalize option, in a fairly inefficient way and I was wondering if there is a way to mitigate this inefficiency.

I've made a small (and a bit silly) toy example to showcase the behavior in question.

```
#define MAX_N 100

typedef struct {
  int n;
  int a[MAX_N];
} N_Array;
```

I then have the following function:

```
void copy (const N_Array* x, N_Array* y) {
  int i;
  N_Array ret = {x->n}; //This seems to be where the problematic behavior arises

  for (i=0; i<x->n; i++) {
    ret.a[i] = x->a[i];
  }

  y->n = ret.n;
  for (i=0; i<ret.n; i++) {
    y->a[i] = ret.a[i];
  }
}
```

The line in which the `n` field of `ret` is assigned appears to trigger a 100 line long initialization of the `a` field, which while conceptually easy to deal with (100 or so `forward`s) is nearly impossible to actually get through due to the time it takes and only gets worse as the value of `MAX_N` becomes larger.

I hope this isn't too esoteric a question to ask, but is there either a "better" version of `forward` I can use for this situation, or an easy way to circumvent this initialization behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the local-variable initialization    `N_Array ret = {x->n};`  really does cause the C compiler to emit 100 assignment statements.  Best to write the program as,

```
  N_Array ret;
  ret.n = x->n;
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew.  Part of me was hoping to not change the source, but I had a feeling this would be the case.